# Passwordless Email Deny Specific Domains

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a user journey that is very similar to the ["social and local account" policy.](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/sign-up-with-social-and-local-account/readme.md)

My "social" accounts are actually SAML for my company. So they always end with company.com.

My local accounts are using [passwordless flow](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/Readme.md), and should never end in company.com.

I have come up with a claims transformation that may help:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="IsInvalidEmailTransformation" TransformationMethod="StringCollectionContains">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="wustl.edu" />
    <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IsInvalidEmailForPasswordless" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

However, I am unsure where to put this in my journey. I am not sure how to detect if I am in a passwordless step, and if so, how to halt the users progress and throw errors.

My User Journey is as follows:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="LocalOrWashuIDPSignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="COMPANYAKeySAML" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignIn-WithEmail" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUp-WithEmail" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="COMPANYAKeySAML" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="companya-IDP-SAML" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignIn-WithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress-SignIn" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUp-WithEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-Custom" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- Show self-asserted page only if they are new (no object id yet), and used passwordless email (only local account option today) -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Local" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Local" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
                  in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>companyaShibIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Local) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
            from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
            (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- The next steps attempt to set the WuPeopleOrObjectId special claim for DestinyOne -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SetWuPeopleIdForGenericDestinyOneOutputClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Set-WuPeopleId-ForGenericDestinyOneOutputClaim" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>companyaShibIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SetObjectIdForGenericDestinyOneOutputClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Set-ObjectId-ForGenericDestinyOneOutputClaim" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- See SignUpOrSignIn policy for SAML for SendClaims -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>

  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
  
</UserJourney>
```